# Testcafe with Browserstack stops to run tests in the middle

Tags: jenkins, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, browserstack

I run Testcafe (^1.8.6) from a Jenkins server and use Browserstack and the module testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack (^1.13.0). The TESTCAFE_BROWSERSTACK_API_POLLING_INTERVAL is set to 40 seconds. While the tests are running, in somehow random changing places, the browser loses the connection to the website (it can be seen in the videos). From my local computer the tests run fine. What can i do to make the tests run reliable and complete?

Comment: Do you run your test concurrently? If so, try to turn off the concurrency mode.

Also, you can create an issue in the [TestCafe repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe) and attach a simple project where this problem can be reproduced. We'll research it and will try to find a solution.

Comment: No, i do not run them concurrently. The Browserstack support team told me to set BROWSERSTACK_FORCE_LOCAL to 1. I don't know if thats the reason, but it seems not to fail as often as before.

Comment: Also, you can try the following experimental TestCafe package: `npm i --save-dev https://git.io/JJZoa`. It should handle possible network issues.